# Calling of one method in matlab package inside other method of same package

Tags: matlab

I am experiencing some problem while calling a method from matlab package because that method is calling another method of same package. In script I call method by specifying name of package which contains the method and call to this method works fine. However when method inside package try to call other method of same package then code crashes. Structure of my package is like this:

+pkg\methodA

+pkg\methodB

```
function methodA ()
    methodB()
end

function methodB ()
    disp ('Hello')
end
```

In methodA when I call methodB, I am not specifying the package name prior to method name. I want to check whether this implementation is incorrect or I am missing something.

Is this correct way of calling methodB:

```
function methodA ()
   pkg.methodB()
end
```

Error message:

```
Undefined function or variable 'methodB'.
Error in pkg.methodA (line 4)
    methodB () ;
```

Comment: what do you mean by package?

Comment: if we put + sign prior to name of folder containing methods then it become package. More details can be found here: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html

Comment: can you include the actual code and the actual error message?

Comment: Package functions need to be called with full package prefix always. You can import packages to avoid using this prefix.

Comment: Could you include proper determiners in your text? It's really hard to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the package name as a prefix in each function call (`pkg.methodB()`) or you have to import `pkg` using `import pkg.*`.

Possible implementations are:

```
function methodA ()
pkg.methodB()
end
```

.

```
function methodA ()
import pkg.*
methodB()
end
```

Comment: I tried to import the pkg in script or command window and still I am getting error when I tried to execute methodA. However methodB execute normally.

Comment: You need to import in methodA

Comment: ok. But does not it strange that methods from same package do not have knowledge about each other.

Comment: It might be impractical, but you have to import functions from the same package.